# "you don't...without...."

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

A and B are going to take a bomb-defusing class tomorrow.

> A: I am going to dominate that class. ***You don't cross-stitch for 20
>   years without developing a steady hand***.
>
> B: Wow, you really think that is a brag, don't you? 20 bucks says, I
>   do better in that class than you do.
>
> A: All right, you're on.

---

C is super drunk and A is offering to sober her up.

> A: I got this. I'm a master at sobering up.
>
> B: Are you sure?
>
> A: Uh, ***you don't go to the Renaissance Faire every weekend in your 20s
>   without learning how to handle your mead***.
>
> B: Great. Thanks, C

I hardly understand what these marked sentences mean. I definitely don't understand the construction, though. Why do they use "don't" here, not "didn't" or "haven't" ?

Those dialogues was taken from an sitcom.

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* because they are general, timeless statements, for which we usually use the the present simple. "You" is here an indefinite pronoun, not the second person (addressee).